# WAT: more elegant way to achieve Horner's method

Tags: webassembly

I'm applying [Horner's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method) in [WAT](https://webassembly.github.io/spec/core/text/index.html). Expressed in my own arbitrary syntax, the algorithm is basically:

```
horner(baseValue, T1, T2, T3) {
  return T1+(T2*baseValue²)+(T3*baseValue³)
}
```

`T1, T2, T3` is arbitrarily extendable: `T4`, `T5`, etc, might be called for. Ideally, it would be great if the function's T parameters were variadic. In other words, it would be great if I could use the WAT equivalent of:

```
horner(baseValue, ...T)
```

And then do something along the lines of what commenthol does in the excellent [astronomia](https://github.com/commenthol/astronomia/blob/5daa9da53f05def704fbce6103f04cc3d9613bad/src/base.js#L299) library:

```
let i = T.length - 1
  let y = c[T]
  while (i > 0) {
    i--
    y = y * x + T[i]
  }
  return y
```

Far as I can tell, there is no WAT equivalent of variadic parameters. I think that I need to approach the algorithm differently.

Here is the most performant function that I can think of:

```
(func $horner
    ;;     0
    (param $x f64)
    ;;     1   2   3   4   5
    ;;     +   *x  *x2 *x3 *x4 
    (param f64 f64 f64 f64 f64)
    (result f64)

    ;; x to the fourth
    local.get 5
    local.get $x
    local.get $x
    local.get $x
    local.get $x
    f64.mul
    f64.mul
    f64.mul
    f64.mul

    ;; x to the third
    local.get 4
    local.get $x
    local.get $x
    local.get $x
    f64.mul
    f64.mul
    f64.mul

    ;; x squared
    local.get 3
    local.get $x
    local.get $x
    f64.mul
    f64.mul

    ;; x to the first
    local.get 2
    local.get $x
    f64.mul

    ;; add all the terms together
    local.get 1
    f64.add
    f64.add
    f64.add
    f64.add

)
```

I could extend the set of parameters as far as need be and pass zero if a parameter is uneeded, but that would also cause some unneeded calculations. I think that the best approach would be to create horner2 for 2 parameters, horner3 for 3 parameters, and so on.

Is there a more elegant, equally performant approach?

Answer (score 1):

The WebAssembly functions do not have variable number of parameters.

One possible solution I see is to use the linear memory for this job: store the parameters into the linear memory, pass the address to this list/array and the number of elements as parameters, then loop for all values into the linear memory (last to first as it seems) do the math and return the final value. To have any kind of types, you can supply the expected type as an `u32` value and dynamically read from the memory, what this type is.

Because the caller is able to push all of the arguments into the stack, then that means that instead of calling this function and passing the arguments as parameters, you could pop from the stack (on top is the last value) do the math, pop one more value from the stack and so on. In the end after all this values are used you have the final result. The problem here is that you have to "inline" this logic for every caller. To have any kind of types, you must also care with each value its type or have one type for all values and dynamically pop from the stack what ever should be there.